# Twilio Voicemail, if call unanswered

Tags: c#, twilio

I am using Twilio for making voice calls. I would like to know, if there is a way to know when the call is unanswered or failed I need to send the same message as voicemail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio has [Answering Machine Detection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/answering-machine-detection)

Answer (score 0):

Try add a 'machineDetection: "DetectMessageEnd"' to your call parameters. And for your information, that will cost additionally $0.0075 to each call. And try to avoid to add the sendDigits and the machineDetection parameters at the same time.

Also, as you are testing it, there might be no voice unless you make some sound after you pickup the call, because Twilio will detect sounds for a default 30s to determine the "answered by" type then say the text you set. One way to solve this is to set another call parameter , 'machineDetectionTimeout:18'. This decides the This will probably leave a proper message at your voicemail. Good luck!